# How do I fix these foreign key constraints errors?

Tags: sql

I am getting these errors when I run this sql script:

Errors:

> Error code -1, SQL state 23503: INSERT on table 'EVENT_SEAT_SET'
>   caused a violation of foreign key
>   constraint 'SQL110304124417741' for
>   key (Event_Seat_Set1
>   ).  The statement has been rolled
>   back.
>   Line 360, column 1

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE TicketSeller
(
id CHAR(40),
Name1  VARCHAR(50),
Address VARCHAR(100),
Telephone VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Venue
(
id CHAR(40),
Owner VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES TicketSeller(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Venue_Configuration
(
id CHAR(40),
Name1 VARCHAR(50),
Description1 VARCHAR(255),
TotalSeats VARCHAR(50),
VenueID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueID) REFERENCES Venue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE SectionInVenue
(
id CHAR(40),
VenueID CHAR(40),
SectionNumber CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueID) REFERENCES Venue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE RowInVenue
(
id CHAR(40),
SectionID CHAR(40),
RowNumber CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (SectionID) REFERENCES SectionInVenue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Venue_Seat
(
id CHAR(40),
RowID CHAR(40),
SeatNumber CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (RowID) REFERENCES RowInVenue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Venue_Production_Category
(
id CHAR(40),
Description1 VARCHAR(255),
Category VARCHAR(50),
DateTime DATE,
Morning DOUBLE,
Afternoon DOUBLE,
Evening DOUBLE,
VenueID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueID) REFERENCES Venue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Production
(
id CHAR(40),
Name1  VARCHAR(50),
Description1 VARCHAR(255),
StartDate DATE,
EndDate DATE,
Comission DOUBLE,
CategoryID CHAR(40),
Venue_ConfigurationID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Venue_Production_Category(id),
FOREIGN KEY (Venue_ConfigurationID) REFERENCES Venue_Configuration(id)
);

CREATE TABLE TS_Owes_Venue
(
id CHAR(40),
AmountOwed DOUBLE,
TicketSellerid CHAR(40),
Venueid CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (TicketSellerid) REFERENCES TicketSeller(id),
FOREIGN KEY (Venueid) REFERENCES Venue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE TS_Payment
(
id CHAR(40),
DateReceived DATE,
TS_Owes_Venueid CHAR(40),
PaymentType VARCHAR(50),
PaymentAmt DOUBLE,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (TS_Owes_Venueid) REFERENCES TS_Owes_Venue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
id CHAR(40),
Name1  VARCHAR(50),
Address VARCHAR(100),
Telephone VARCHAR(12),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment
(
id CHAR(40),
DateReceived DATE,
PaymentType VARCHAR(100),
PaymentAmt DOUBLE,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Sale
(
id CHAR(40),
DateOfPurchase DATE,
Tax DOUBLE,
TotalPricePaid DOUBLE,
TicketSellerid CHAR(40),
Paymentid CHAR(40),
CustID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (Paymentid) REFERENCES Payment(id),
FOREIGN KEY (TicketSellerid) REFERENCES TicketSeller(id),
FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES Customer(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Sale_Item
(
id CHAR(40),
Discount DOUBLE,
Type1 VARCHAR(50),
StandardPrice DOUBLE,
PricePaid DOUBLE,
Commission DOUBLE,
SaleID CHAR(40),
VenueID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (SaleID) REFERENCES Sale(id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueID) REFERENCES Venue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Event_Seat_Set
(
id CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Sale_Item(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Physical_Pkg_Set
(
id CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Sale_Item(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Conceptual_Package
(
id CHAR(40),
Name1 VARCHAR(50),
Description1 VARCHAR(255),
Discount DOUBLE,
VenueID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueID) REFERENCES Venue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Physical_Package
(
id CHAR(40),
Status CHAR(40),
PhysPkgSetID CHAR(40),
ConceptualPackageID CHAR(40),
VenueSeatID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (PhysPkgSetID) REFERENCES Physical_Pkg_Set(id),
FOREIGN KEY (ConceptualPackageID) REFERENCES Conceptual_Package(id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueSeatID) REFERENCES Venue_Seat(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Event
(
id CHAR(40),
Name1 VARCHAR(50),
TheDate DATE,
BeginTime VARCHAR(50),
EndTime VARCHAR(50),
Status VARCHAR(50),
ProductionID CHAR(40),
Conceptual_PackageID CHAR(40),
VenueID CHAR(40),


PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (ProductionID) REFERENCES Production(id),
FOREIGN KEY (Conceptual_PackageID) REFERENCES Conceptual_Package(id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueID) REFERENCES Venue(id)
);

CREATE TABLE EventSeat
(
id CHAR(40),
Price DOUBLE,
Status VARCHAR(50),
SetID CHAR(40),
EventID CHAR(40),
VenueSeatID CHAR(40),
PhysicalPackageID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (SetID) REFERENCES Event_Seat_Set(id),
FOREIGN KEY (EventID) REFERENCES Event(id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueSeatID) REFERENCES Venue_Seat(id),
FOREIGN KEY (PhysicalPackageID) REFERENCES Physical_Package(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
id CHAR(40),
Name1 VARCHAR(50),
UserName1 VARCHAR(20),
Password VARCHAR(20),
Type VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Pricing_Schema
(
id CHAR(40),
BasePrice DOUBLE,
DateTime DATE,
VPCid CHAR(40),
VenueSeatID CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (VPCid) REFERENCES Venue_Production_Category(id),
FOREIGN KEY (VenueSeatID) REFERENCES Venue_Seat(id)
);


INSERT INTO TicketSeller (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('TicketSeller1','Dominic Grant','479-1881 Tempus Street','7075205001');
INSERT INTO TicketSeller (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('TicketSeller2','Kennedy Perkins','698-1150 Non St.','3834072314');
INSERT INTO TicketSeller (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('TicketSeller3','Keaton Kidd','P.O. Box 990, 4639 Varius Ave','6252363833');
INSERT INTO TicketSeller (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('TicketSeller4','Basil Ryan','P.O. Box 918, 5123 Libero St.','4927231780');
INSERT INTO TicketSeller (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('TicketSeller5','Joshua Bell','Ap #392-5320 Phasellus St.','8612545635');

INSERT INTO Venue (id,Owner) VALUES ('TicketSeller1','Heather Singleton');
INSERT INTO Venue (id,Owner) VALUES ('TicketSeller2','Melodie Arnold');
INSERT INTO Venue (id,Owner) VALUES ('TicketSeller3','Buffy Gordon');
INSERT INTO Venue (id,Owner) VALUES ('TicketSeller4','Autumn Yang');
INSERT INTO Venue (id,Owner) VALUES ('TicketSeller5','Cynthia Fitzgerald');

INSERT INTO Venue_Configuration (id,Name1,Description1,TotalSeats,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Configuration1','at risus.','mattis velit justo nec ante. Maecenas mi felis, adipiscing fringilla, porttitor vulputate, posuere vulputate, lacus.','288','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO Venue_Configuration (id,Name1,Description1,TotalSeats,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Configuration2','molestie pharetra','fringilla purus mauris a nunc. In at pede. Cras vulputate velit eu sem. Pellentesque ut ipsum ac mi','64','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO Venue_Configuration (id,Name1,Description1,TotalSeats,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Configuration3','velit.','vitae velit egestas lacinia. Sed congue, elit sed consequat auctor, nunc nulla vulputate dui, nec tempus mauris erat eget ipsum. Suspendisse','94','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO Venue_Configuration (id,Name1,Description1,TotalSeats,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Configuration4','augue','sapien. Aenean massa. Integer vitae nibh. Donec est mauris, rhoncus id, mollis nec, cursus a, enim. Suspendisse aliquet, sem ut','573','TicketSeller4');
INSERT INTO Venue_Configuration (id,Name1,Description1,TotalSeats,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Configuration5','dignissim tempor','auctor, velit eget laoreet posuere, enim nisl elementum purus, accumsan interdum libero dui nec','761','TicketSeller5');

INSERT INTO SectionInVenue (id,SectionNumber,VenueID) VALUES ('SectionInVenue1','4','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO SectionInVenue (id,SectionNumber,VenueID) VALUES ('SectionInVenue2','16','TicketSeller2');
INSERT INTO SectionInVenue (id,SectionNumber,VenueID) VALUES ('SectionInVenue3','3','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO SectionInVenue (id,SectionNumber,VenueID) VALUES ('SectionInVenue4','19','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO SectionInVenue (id,SectionNumber,VenueID) VALUES ('SectionInVenue5','18','TicketSeller5');

INSERT INTO RowInVenue (id,RowNumber,SectionID) VALUES ('RowInVenue1','5','SectionInVenue1');
INSERT INTO RowInVenue (id,RowNumber,SectionID) VALUES ('RowInVenue2','3','SectionInVenue2');
INSERT INTO RowInVenue (id,RowNumber,SectionID) VALUES ('RowInVenue3','9','SectionInVenue1');
INSERT INTO RowInVenue (id,RowNumber,SectionID) VALUES ('RowInVenue4','1','SectionInVenue4');
INSERT INTO RowInVenue (id,RowNumber,SectionID) VALUES ('RowInVenue5','5','SectionInVenue1');

INSERT INTO Venue_Seat (id,SeatNumber,RowID) VALUES ('Venue_Seat1','33','RowInVenue1');
INSERT INTO Venue_Seat (id,SeatNumber,RowID) VALUES ('Venue_Seat2','49','RowInVenue2');
INSERT INTO Venue_Seat (id,SeatNumber,RowID) VALUES ('Venue_Seat3','40','RowInVenue1');
INSERT INTO Venue_Seat (id,SeatNumber,RowID) VALUES ('Venue_Seat4','27','RowInVenue4');
INSERT INTO Venue_Seat (id,SeatNumber,RowID) VALUES ('Venue_Seat5','5','RowInVenue1');

INSERT INTO Venue_Production_Category (id,Description1,Category,DateTime,Morning,Afternoon,Evening,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Production_Category1','12','metus urna','2011-04-26 16:41:05',100,110,140,'TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO Venue_Production_Category (id,Description1,Category,DateTime,Morning,Afternoon,Evening,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Production_Category2','37','turpis vitae','2011-08-03 06:39:51',10,11,14,'TicketSeller2');
INSERT INTO Venue_Production_Category (id,Description1,Category,DateTime,Morning,Afternoon,Evening,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Production_Category3','20','non','2010-07-31 16:13:59',100.99,110.89,140.78,'TicketSeller3');
INSERT INTO Venue_Production_Category (id,Description1,Category,DateTime,Morning,Afternoon,Evening,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Production_Category4','31','nec luctus','2010-04-21 15:52:05',100.78,110.89,140.78,'TicketSeller4');
INSERT INTO Venue_Production_Category (id,Description1,Category,DateTime,Morning,Afternoon,Evening,VenueID) VALUES ('Venue_Production_Category5','32','lectus','2010-02-10 06:03:13',100.5,110.45,140.45,'TicketSeller5');

INSERT INTO Production (id,Name1,Description1,StartDate,EndDate,Comission,CategoryID,Venue_ConfigurationID) VALUES ('Production1','dolor.','eros turpis non enim. Mauris quis turpis vitae purus gravida sagittis. Duis gravida. Praesent eu nulla at sem molestie sodales.','2012-01-09 20:24:01','2010-12-20 02:43:01',.25,'Venue_Production_Category1','Venue_Configuration1');
INSERT INTO Production (id,Name1,Description1,StartDate,EndDate,Comission,CategoryID,Venue_ConfigurationID) VALUES ('Production2','at,','sed dolor. Fusce mi lorem, vehicula et, rutrum eu, ultrices sit amet, risus. Donec nibh enim,','2010-12-06 15:26:23','2010-03-25 21:32:48',.2,'Venue_Production_Category2','Venue_Configuration5');
INSERT INTO Production (id,Name1,Description1,StartDate,EndDate,Comission,CategoryID,Venue_ConfigurationID) VALUES ('Production3','lorem','condimentum eget, volutpat ornare, facilisis eget, ipsum. Donec sollicitudin adipiscing ligula. Aenean gravida nunc sed pede. Cum sociis','2011-11-11 07:50:27','2011-04-14 13:20:14',.1,'Venue_Production_Category3','Venue_Configuration2');
INSERT INTO Production (id,Name1,Description1,StartDate,EndDate,Comission,CategoryID,Venue_ConfigurationID) VALUES ('Production4','metus','mauris ipsum porta elit, a feugiat tellus lorem eu metus. In lorem. Donec elementum, lorem ut aliquam iaculis,','2011-09-23 14:29:58','2010-08-22 03:16:56',.15,'Venue_Production_Category4', 'Venue_Configuration3');
INSERT INTO Production (id,Name1,Description1,StartDate,EndDate,Comission,CategoryID,Venue_ConfigurationID) VALUES ('Production5','vel,','auctor quis, tristique ac, eleifend vitae, erat. Vivamus nisi. Mauris nulla. Integer urna. Vivamus molestie dapibus ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla dignissim. Maecenas ornare','2011-10-07 13:47:35','2011-08-20 13:22:40',.15,'Venue_Production_Category5','Venue_Configuration4');

INSERT INTO TS_Owes_Venue (id,AmountOwed,TicketSellerid,Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Owes_TicketSeller1', 439,'TicketSeller1','TicketSeller5');
INSERT INTO TS_Owes_Venue (id,AmountOwed,TicketSellerid,Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Owes_TicketSeller2', 121,'TicketSeller2','TicketSeller3');
INSERT INTO TS_Owes_Venue (id,AmountOwed,TicketSellerid,Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Owes_TicketSeller3', 549,'TicketSeller3','TicketSeller4');
INSERT INTO TS_Owes_Venue (id,AmountOwed,TicketSellerid,Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Owes_TicketSeller4', 265,'TicketSeller4','TicketSeller2');
INSERT INTO TS_Owes_Venue (id,AmountOwed,TicketSellerid,Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Owes_TicketSeller5', 76,'TicketSeller5','TicketSeller1');

INSERT INTO TS_Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt,TS_Owes_Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Payment1','2009-09-02 08:49:15','sollicitudin orci',292,'TS_Owes_TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO TS_Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt,TS_Owes_Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Payment2','2011-09-15 22:05:43','tristique',801,'TS_Owes_TicketSeller2');
INSERT INTO TS_Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt,TS_Owes_Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Payment3','2009-08-05 05:58:18','erat',735,'TS_Owes_TicketSeller3');
INSERT INTO TS_Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt,TS_Owes_Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Payment4','2010-01-30 05:20:23','a feugiat',744,'TS_Owes_TicketSeller4');
INSERT INTO TS_Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt,TS_Owes_Venueid) VALUES ('TS_Payment5','2011-11-03 03:16:52','eu elit.',268,'TS_Owes_TicketSeller5');

INSERT INTO Customer (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('Customer1','Igor Cervantes','654-2441 Nunc St.','435-768-0213');
INSERT INTO Customer (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('Customer2','Barry Farmer','902-5703 Et Rd.','577-435-7872');
INSERT INTO Customer (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('Customer3','Shad Barber','347-6930 Ipsum St.','285-317-5292');
INSERT INTO Customer (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('Customer4','Stone Hester','9147 Luctus, Road','232-801-5395');
INSERT INTO Customer (id,Name1,Address,Telephone) VALUES ('Customer5','Darius Battle','Ap #292-4270 Elit. Rd.','345-908-9273');

INSERT INTO Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt) VALUES ('Payment1','2011-04-06 19:18:25','mauris ut',179.89);
INSERT INTO Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt) VALUES ('Payment2','2009-03-18 17:28:45','ac',87.7);
INSERT INTO Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt) VALUES ('Payment3','2009-11-17 16:34:33','Maecenas',6.90);
INSERT INTO Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt) VALUES ('Payment4','2010-08-21 22:08:43','nulla',76.5);
INSERT INTO Payment (id,DateReceived,PaymentType,PaymentAmt) VALUES ('Payment5','2011-03-26 04:46:19','vel sapien',54.9);

INSERT INTO Sale (id,DateOfPurchase,Tax,TotalPricePaid,Paymentid,TicketSellerid,CustID) VALUES ('Sale1','2011-08-28 17:28:14',1.45,62.56,'Payment1','TicketSeller1','Customer1');
INSERT INTO Sale (id,DateOfPurchase,Tax,TotalPricePaid,Paymentid,TicketSellerid,CustID) VALUES ('Sale2','2011-02-08 15:03:15',6.80,7.50,'Payment2','TicketSeller2','Customer2');
INSERT INTO Sale (id,DateOfPurchase,Tax,TotalPricePaid,Paymentid,TicketSellerid,CustID) VALUES ('Sale3','2011-11-24 01:39:58',1.10,12.35,'Payment3','TicketSeller3','Customer3');
INSERT INTO Sale (id,DateOfPurchase,Tax,TotalPricePaid,Paymentid,TicketSellerid,CustID) VALUES ('Sale4','2011-01-06 23:06:57',2.40,62.56,'Payment4','TicketSeller4','Customer4');
INSERT INTO Sale (id,DateOfPurchase,Tax,TotalPricePaid,Paymentid,TicketSellerid,CustID) VALUES ('Sale5','2011-01-01 09:28:54',1.45,62.56,'Payment5','TicketSeller5','Customer5');

INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item1',20.00,'velit',45.00,25.00,6.80,'Sale1','TicketSeller3');
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item2',10.00,'velit',40.00,33.00,4.40,'Sale5','TicketSeller4');
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item3',3.00,'velit',35.00,20.00,7.30,'Sale3','TicketSeller2');
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item4',5.00,'velit',50.00,47.00,2.50,'Sale4','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item5',6.00,'velit',25.00,12.00,6.10,'Sale2','TicketSeller5');

INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set1');
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set2');
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set3');
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set4');
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set5');

INSERT INTO Physical_Pkg_Set (id) VALUES ('Physical_Pkg_Set1');
INSERT INTO Physical_Pkg_Set (id) VALUES ('Physical_Pkg_Set2');
INSERT INTO Physical_Pkg_Set (id) VALUES ('Physical_Pkg_Set3');
INSERT INTO Physical_Pkg_Set (id) VALUES ('Physical_Pkg_Set4');
INSERT INTO Physical_Pkg_Set (id) VALUES ('Physical_Pkg_Set5');

INSERT INTO Conceptual_Package (id,Name1,Description1,VenueID) VALUES ('Conceptual_Package1','egestas','eleifend non, dapibus rutrum, justo. Praesent luctus. Curabitur egestas nunc','TicketSeller3');
INSERT INTO Conceptual_Package (id,Name1,Description1,VenueID) VALUES ('Conceptual_Package2','Ut','Nunc mauris. Morbi non sapien molestie orci tincidunt adipiscing. Mauris molestie pharetra nibh.','TicketSeller3');
INSERT INTO Conceptual_Package (id,Name1,Description1,VenueID) VALUES ('Conceptual_Package3','Vivamus','accumsan sed, facilisis vitae, orci. Phasellus dapibus quam quis diam. Pellentesque habitant','TicketSeller4');
INSERT INTO Conceptual_Package (id,Name1,Description1,VenueID) VALUES ('Conceptual_Package4','egestas','tincidunt nibh. Phasellus nulla. Integer vulputate, risus a ultricies adipiscing, enim mi tempor lorem, eget mollis lectus pede et','TicketSeller5');
INSERT INTO Conceptual_Package (id,Name1,Description1,VenueID) VALUES ('Conceptual_Package5','arcu.','Nullam feugiat placerat velit. Quisque varius. Nam porttitor scelerisque neque. Nullam nisl. Maecenas malesuada fringilla est. Mauris eu turpis.','TicketSeller2');

INSERT INTO Physical_Package (id,Status,PhysPkgSetID,ConceptualPackageID,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('Physical_Package1','Open','Physical_Pkg_Set1','Conceptual_Package4','Venue_Seat2');
INSERT INTO Physical_Package (id,Status,PhysPkgSetID,ConceptualPackageID,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('Physical_Package2','Open','Physical_Pkg_Set3','Conceptual_Package1','Venue_Seat5');
INSERT INTO Physical_Package (id,Status,PhysPkgSetID,ConceptualPackageID,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('Physical_Package3','Open','Physical_Pkg_Set2','Conceptual_Package3','Venue_Seat1');
INSERT INTO Physical_Package (id,Status,PhysPkgSetID,ConceptualPackageID,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('Physical_Package4','Open','Physical_Pkg_Set5','Conceptual_Package2','Venue_Seat3');
INSERT INTO Physical_Package (id,Status,PhysPkgSetID,ConceptualPackageID,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('Physical_Package5','Open','Physical_Pkg_Set4','Conceptual_Package5','Venue_Seat4');

INSERT INTO Event (id,Name1,TheDate,BeginTime,EndTime,Status,ProductionID,Conceptual_PackageID,VenueID) VALUES ('Event1','Dave Mathews','2011-11-16 11:58:51','2011-04-24 00:44:18','2011-09-05 18:01:45','In','Production1','Conceptual_Package1','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO Event (id,Name1,TheDate,BeginTime,EndTime,Status,ProductionID,Conceptual_PackageID,VenueID) VALUES ('Event2','Jack Johsnon','2008-09-30 01:52:32','2011-03-17 01:15:34','2010-03-26 20:04:12','ipsum','Production2','Conceptual_Package2','TicketSeller2');
INSERT INTO Event (id,Name1,TheDate,BeginTime,EndTime,Status,ProductionID,Conceptual_PackageID,VenueID) VALUES ('Event3','Sweeeny Todd','2010-12-12 22:31:59','2010-03-27 23:53:10','2011-02-12 03:10:04','Sed eu','Production3','Conceptual_Package3','TicketSeller2');
INSERT INTO Event (id,Name1,TheDate,BeginTime,EndTime,Status,ProductionID,Conceptual_PackageID,VenueID) VALUES ('Event4','Run DMC','2010-05-04 08:14:51','2011-07-20 05:59:40','2011-04-26 23:27:27','ac','Production4','Conceptual_Package4','TicketSeller5');
INSERT INTO Event (id,Name1,TheDate,BeginTime,EndTime,Status,ProductionID,Conceptual_PackageID,VenueID) VALUES ('Event5','Jazz vs Nets','2011-08-14 01:31:53','2010-09-07 01:14:19','2011-12-14 08:21:50','ridiculus','Production5','Conceptual_Package5','TicketSeller3');

INSERT INTO EventSeat (id,Price,Status,SetID,EventID,VenueSeatID, PhysicalPackageID) VALUES ('EventSeat1',12.50,'Sold','Event_Seat_Set1','Event1','Venue_Seat1', 'Physical_Package1');
INSERT INTO EventSeat (id,Price,Status,SetID,EventID,VenueSeatID, PhysicalPackageID) VALUES ('EventSeat2',13.00,'Sold','Event_Seat_Set2','Event2','Venue_Seat2', 'Physical_Package2');
INSERT INTO EventSeat (id,Price,Status,SetID,EventID,VenueSeatID, PhysicalPackageID) VALUES ('EventSeat3',13.50,'Sold','Event_Seat_Set3','Event3','Venue_Seat3', 'Physical_Package3');
INSERT INTO EventSeat (id,Price,Status,SetID,EventID,VenueSeatID, PhysicalPackageID) VALUES ('EventSeat4',11.00,'Sold','Event_Seat_Set4','Event4','Venue_Seat4', 'Physical_Package4');
INSERT INTO EventSeat (id,Price,Status,SetID,EventID,VenueSeatID, PhysicalPackageID) VALUES ('EventSeat5',13.00,'Available','Event_Seat_Set5','Event5','Venue_Seat5', 'Physical_Package5');

INSERT INTO Employee (id,Name1,UserName1,Password,Type) VALUES ('Employee1','Boris Wilkins','Meredith','SPY20CST0NF','sed tortor.');
INSERT INTO Employee (id,Name1,UserName1,Password,Type) VALUES ('Employee2','Keaton Fowler','Camilla','VDT77CCG9OH','mus. Donec');
INSERT INTO Employee (id,Name1,UserName1,Password,Type) VALUES ('Employee3','Demetrius Dawson','Harrison','WEP92ISI8XY','quis accumsan');
INSERT INTO Employee (id,Name1,UserName1,Password,Type) VALUES ('Employee4','Cooper Woodward','Donovan','JSB18DKU7SJ','nec,');
INSERT INTO Employee (id,Name1,UserName1,Password,Type) VALUES ('Employee5','Kennedy Rivas','Scarlett','TJU06MIN3HJ','sociis natoque');


INSERT INTO Pricing_Schema (id,BasePrice,DateTime,VPCid,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('1',158,'2008-06-08 11:22:58','Venue_Production_Category1','Venue_Seat1');
INSERT INTO Pricing_Schema (id,BasePrice,DateTime,VPCid,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('2',152,'2011-07-15 18:51:26','Venue_Production_Category2','Venue_Seat2');
INSERT INTO Pricing_Schema (id,BasePrice,DateTime,VPCid,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('3',236,'2010-12-23 10:27:47','Venue_Production_Category3','Venue_Seat3');
INSERT INTO Pricing_Schema (id,BasePrice,DateTime,VPCid,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('4',184,'2011-10-07 03:59:21','Venue_Production_Category4','Venue_Seat4');
INSERT INTO Pricing_Schema (id,BasePrice,DateTime,VPCid,VenueSeatID) VALUES ('5',185,'2011-07-07 18:47:56','Venue_Production_Category5','Venue_Seat5');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Event_Seat_Set` referenced the ID column of `Sale_Item` as a foreign key.

When you are inserting data to the table, you need to insert an existing `Sale_Item` id into the table. You are not inserting anything to that field, hence the insert fail.

This is what is happening with other tables as well - the errors tell you exactly what table has the foreign key and which table it references (and hence, what information you are missing in the insert).

To be honest, I don't even understand the table CREATE statment for `Event_Seat_Set`:

```
CREATE TABLE Event_Seat_Set
(
id CHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Sale_Item(id)
);
```

It seems to state that the table has a single column - `ID` that is both it's primary key and references the `id` column from `Sale_Item`.

This doesn't seem right.

Comment: Oh my freaking goodness, I am embarrassed to have asked this question. Thanks a lot for  pointing out the obvious...!!

Comment: Yes, it doesn't really make sense if that's the only column unless it's a sparse table indicating membership of some special set.  That's the only thing I could think of.  Not a particularly good design even for that.  A lot of times, I'll use a GroupID, ItemID to denote group membership and have a single table for all groups instead of separate tables for different groups.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages are telling you exactly what the problem is. The foreign key constraint is being violated when you are inserting records. Verify the foreign key values are correct (exist) and then retry the script.

EDIT:

here is one of your problems:

```
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set1'); 
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set2'); 
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set3'); 
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set4'); 
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set5');
```

These values need to be keys (ID's that exist in the SaleItem's table).

BTW: I dont really like the schema you have used. IMO you should be using an integer (auto_inc) Primary Key. whilst creating a primary key on a char field is allowed, this inevitably leads to issues like the one you are currently experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

The Event_Seat_Set.id is the PK and also an FK into Sale_Item, which does not have those keys:

```
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item1',20.00,'velit',45.00,25.00,6.80,'Sale1','TicketSeller3');
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item2',10.00,'velit',40.00,33.00,4.40,'Sale5','TicketSeller4');
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item3',3.00,'velit',35.00,20.00,7.30,'Sale3','TicketSeller2');
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item4',5.00,'velit',50.00,47.00,2.50,'Sale4','TicketSeller1');
INSERT INTO Sale_Item (id,Discount,Type1,StandardPrice,PricePaid,Commission,SaleID,VenueID) VALUES ('Sale_Item5',6.00,'velit',25.00,12.00,6.10,'Sale2','TicketSeller5');

INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set1');
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set2');
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set3');
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set4');
INSERT INTO Event_Seat_Set (id) VALUES ('Event_Seat_Set5');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not inserting the foreign keys in the Event_Set_Seat and Physical_Pkg_Set tables. You have to insert these, otherwise the constraint is violated. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp